# How to add ImageView to layout programmatically

Tags: android

I have some problem when add ImageView to Layout. Here are my codes:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative);
    ImageView picture = new ImageView(this);
    picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture1);
    layout.addView(picture);
}
```

There are no errors showed in Eclipse, but when I run it in my device, the program crash.

Comment: what does logcat says?

Comment: The code seems fine. Do you have `RelativeLayout` with id = relative in activity_main.xml?

Comment: 08-01 01:28:30.086: E/AndroidRuntime(11399): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.picture/com.example.picture.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

Comment: @MysticMagic <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#141414"
    tools:context="com.example.picture.Main$PlaceholderFragment" >

Comment: You have NPE on Relative Layout. 

So please make sure that you have RelativeLayout with id = relative in the xml activity_main.

Comment: Post this xml and crash as edit in question. And is this fragment?

Comment: If its fragment, you will need to use like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24508799/1777090)

Comment: @MysticMagic You are right, the problem happened because of fragment. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the NPE for relative layout as its in fragment. So please get it in `onCreateView` of fragment like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_holder_fragment, container, false);
    RelativeLayout layout= (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relative);
    ImageView picture = new ImageView(this);
    picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture1);
    layout.addView(picture);
    return view;
}
```

[Creating fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating)